# How do I capture command-line text that is not sent to stdout?

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, lame

I am using the LAME command line mp3 encoder in a project. I want to be able to see what version someone is using. if I just execute LAME.exe with no paramaters i get, for example:

```
C:\LAME>LAME.exe
LAME 32-bits version 3.98.2 (http://www.mp3dev.org/)

usage: blah blah
blah blah

C:\LAME>
```

if i try redirecting the output to a text file using > to a text file the text file is empty. Where is this text accessable from when running it using System.Process in c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably using stderr.  cmd.exe doesn't allow you to redirect stderr, and the only way I've ever redirected it is with a djgpp tool.

Comment: can i see that in c# using System.Process? I'll look into this now thanks.

Comment: Well maybe I'm wrong, this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110930 says that you can redirect stderr now.

Comment: that's always been possible using cmd

Answer (score 3):

It may be output to stderr instead of stdout.  You can [redirect stderr](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/110930) by doing:

```
LAME.exe 2> textfile.txt
```

If this shows you information, then LAME is outputting to the standard error stream.  If you write a wrapper in C#, you can redirect the [standard error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx) and output streams from [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\LAME\LAME.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        proc.Start();
        string output = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();


        proc.WaitForExit();

        MessageBox.Show(output);
```

worked. thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

It might be sent to stderr, have you tried that?

Check out [Process.StandardError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Try it out using

```
C:\LAME>LAME.exe 2> test.txt
```